# Error in SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update the fact table based on a lookup table. Fact table's `Addressid` needs to be updated and replaced by `newaddress` of lookup column and compared with `oldaddress` column of lookup table.

I have written following SQL statement:

```
Update [dbo].[fact_P] 
Set Address_Id = (Select AddressID_new 
                  From AddressLookup 
                  Where fact_P.Address_Id = Lookup.AddressID_old)
```

but it's throwing an error.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It looks like either SQL Server or Access, I'm leaning towards the former.  But I don't think the error is DB specific.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting? Remember: we **cannot** see your screen, nor **read your mind** - you will have to **tell us!**

Answer (score 0):

You were referencing the `AddressID_old` column in the subquery using the wrong alias/table name.  If I'm not mistaken, you should be using `AddressLookup.Address_ID_old` instead.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[fact_P]
SET Address_Id = (SELECT AddressID_new FROM AddressLookup al
                  WHERE fact_P.Address_Id = al.AddressID_old)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query for UPDATE statement :

```
  UPDATE [dbo].[fact_P] SET Address_Id = AddressID_new 
  FROM AddressLookup al
  WHERE fact_P.Address_Id = al.AddressID_old
```

Answer (score 0):

in where part, subquery is allowed only if it return 1 value. so if I am not mistake by your tables name as Lookup is 'AddressLookup', you need join:

```
Update  fp
 set fp.Address_Id=al.AddressID_new
  from [dbo].[fact_P]  fp join AddressLookup al
      on fp.Address_Id= al.AddressID_old
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tgt
set Address_Id = lu.Address_Id
from [dbo].[fact_P] tgt
inner join AddressLookup lu
on tgt.Address_Id = lu.AddressID_old;
```

Comment: thanks It is working but its take long time as data is huge can we use merge instead to run it faster  any idea

Comment: Merge should be used when you have both insert or Update you need to do on target table from source table. I don't think it will increase performance anyway. You can try doing indexing properly.